# Euler's totient function : A new formula?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have found a formula on Euler's totient function but I have no proof. I need help to demonstrate the formula if possible.

$\phi$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $a$ denotes a natural number > 1 and $n$ denotes a natural number multiple of 4.
If the remainder of the division of $\phi(a^n-2)+1$ by $n$ is equal to $n-1$ then $\phi(a^n-2)+1$ is always a prime number.

Example with $a=119$ and $n=20$:
The remainder of the division of $\phi(119^{20}-2)+1$ by $20$ is equal to $19$, and $\phi(119^{20}-2)+1$ is prime.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The following has nothing to do with the question. Numerically verifying the assertion I got the primes 4999, 79999, 6479999, 1088391167999999999999, 11264199772469587205920073937386320499999999999999999999999999999999999 Strange?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478597/eulers-totient-function-and-primes#)